# Find the distance between two lines in $ \Bbb R^3 $

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

There are two lines in $ \Bbb R^3 $ given in parametric form:
$$
l_1:
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x &= x_1 +a_1t\\ 
y &= y_1 +b_1t \\ 
z &= z_1 +c_1t \\
\end{aligned} 
\right.
$$
$$
l_2:
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x &= x_2 +a_2s \\ 
y &= y_2 +b_2s \\ 
z &= z_2 +c_2s \\
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

What's the simplest method (or formula) for finding (the shortest) distance beteen them?

---

example I'm doing:
$
l_1:
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x &= 0 \\ 
y &= -1 - 2t \\ 
z &= -2t \\
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$

$
l_2:
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x &= 3s \\ 
y &= 1 - s \\ 
z &= 2 + 4s \\
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$

Comment: I tried giving [a solution to this problem in the linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/429434/67270). Could someone check if it's correct, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Find a vector $\mathbf A$ perpendicular to both lines and then find the projection onto $\mathbf A$ of *any* vector joining $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$. Pictures help.

Comment: That's a very clever and concise way to go about it, giving a simple form for the answer.