# Equation of line of shortest distance

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

Given two lines $r_1=3i+5j+7k+m(i-2j+7k)$ and $r_2=-i-j-k+n(7i-6k+j)$ how to find the equation of line of shortest distance?

I found the direction ratios of line of shortest distance as (2,3,4) but how do I take the point through which it passes?

Comment: Related [shortest distance between two lines](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210848/finding-the-shortest-distance-between-two-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of shortest distance between the two given lines will be perpendicular to both.  Therefore, you can take the cross product of the direction vectors to find the direction of shortest distance.

Now, you need to find two points on the two lines that are in that direction of each other.  To do this, you could construct the plane including one of the given lines along with the direction vector of the segment of shortest distance.  Then compute the intersection of that plane with the second line.