# how to write down shortest distance between lines in R^n

Tags: determinant, convex-optimization, closed-form

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ two lines pass through $A$ and $B$, respectively, and their directions $r_1$ and $r_2$ (which are non-zero and non-parallel)

I know for $n=3$ the minimal euclidean distance between points on each line can be written

$$\frac{|(r_1\times r_2)\cdot AB|}{||r_1\times r_2||_2}$$

If $n$ is larger, is it possible to write something with determinants that works for all larger $n$?

Comment: These two lines span a $3$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Hence you can reduce the problem to $n=3$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz do you mean transforming the vectors by orthogonal matrices in a way that results in only 3 coordinates being non zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indicating by $\mathbf a$, $\mathbf b$, $\mathbf {p_1}$ and $\mathbf {p_2}$ the position vectors 
of the point $A$, $B$, generic point on line 1 and on line 2, then the parametric equations
of the two lines will be
$$
{\bf p}_{\,1}  = {\bf a} + \lambda \,{\bf r}_{\,1} \quad {\bf p}_{\,2}  = {\bf b} + \mu \,{\bf r}_{\,2} 
$$

Now impose that the difference vector  between the two generic point
be normal to each line
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  \left( {{\bf p}_{\,1}  - {\bf p}_{\,2} } \right) \cdot {\bf r}_{\,1}  = 0 \hfill \cr 
  \left( {{\bf p}_{\,1}  - {\bf p}_{\,2} } \right) \cdot {\bf r}_{\,2}  = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  \left( {{\bf a} + \lambda {\bf r}_{\,1}  - {\bf b} - \mu {\bf r}_{\,2} } \right) \cdot {\bf r}_{\,1}  = 0 \hfill \cr 
  \left( {{\bf a} + \lambda {\bf r}_{\,1}  - {\bf b} - \mu {\bf r}_{\,2} } \right) \cdot {\bf r}_{\,2}  = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf r}_{\,1}  \cdot {\bf r}_{\,1} \,\lambda  - {\bf r}_{\,2}  \cdot {\bf r}_{\,1} \,\mu  = \left( {{\bf b} - {\bf a}} \right) \cdot {\bf r}_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  {\bf r}_{\,2}  \cdot {\bf r}_{\,1} \,\lambda  - {\bf r}_{\,2}  \cdot {\bf r}_{\,2} \,\mu  = \left( {{\bf b} - {\bf a}} \right) \cdot {\bf r}_{\,2}  \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
you get a simple linear system in the unknowns $\lambda$ and $\mu$.
After solving that, it is easy to find the modulus of ${\bf p}_{\,1}  - {\bf p}_{\,2} $.

**----    Addendum  -  Matrix notation    -----**

Indicating
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf P} = \left( {{\bf p}_{\,1} |{\bf p}_{\,2} } \right)\quad {\bf R} = \left( {{\bf r}_{\,1} |{\bf r}_{\,2} } \right)\quad {\bf C} = \left( {{\bf a}|{\bf b}} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf \Lambda } = \left( {\matrix{
   \lambda  & 0  \cr 
   0 & \mu   \cr 
 } } \right)\quad {\bf u} = \left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   { - 1}  \cr 
 } } \right) \cr} 
$$
then

- the parametric equations become
  $$
  {\bf P = C + R}\;{\bf \Lambda }
  $$
- the vector connecting generic points on the two lines is
  $$
  {\bf d} = {\bf P}\,{\bf u}
  $$
- the orthogonality condition becomes
  $$
  \eqalign{
    & {\bf 0} = {\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf P}\,{\bf u} = {\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf C}\,{\bf u + R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}\;{\bf \Lambda }\,{\bf u}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad   \cr 
    &  \Rightarrow \quad \;{\bf \Lambda }\,{\bf u} =  - \;\left( {{\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf C}\,{\bf u} \cr} 
  $$
- which gives as the ${\bf d}$ normal to both lines
  $$
  \eqalign{
    & {\bf d}_ \bot   = {\bf C}\,{\bf u + R}\;{\bf \Lambda }\,{\bf u} = {\bf C}\,{\bf u} - {\bf R}\;\left( {{\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf C}\,{\bf u} =   \cr 
    &  = \left( {{\bf I} - {\bf R}\;\left( {{\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf R}^{\bf T} } \right){\bf C}\,{\bf u} \cr} 
  $$
- whose squared modulus is (the core matrix in ${\bf R}$ is idempotent)

  > $$
  > \eqalign{
  >   & \left| {{\bf d}_ \bot  } \right|^{\,2}  = {\bf d}_ \bot  ^{\bf T} \;{\bf d}_ \bot   = {\bf u}^{\bf T} \,{\bf C}^{\bf T} \,\left( {{\bf I} - {\bf R}\;\left( {{\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf R}^{\bf T} } \right)^{\,2} {\bf C}\,{\bf u} =   \cr 
  >   &  = {\bf u}^{\bf T} \,{\bf C}^{\bf T} \,\left( {{\bf I} - {\bf R}\;\left( {{\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf R}^{\bf T} } \right){\bf C}\,{\bf u} \cr} 
  > $$

It is interesting to note that for the said matrix we have 
$$
\left( {{\bf I} - {\bf R}\;\left( {{\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf R}^{\bf T} } \right){\bf R} = {\bf R}^{\bf T} \left( {{\bf I} - {\bf R}\;\left( {{\bf R}^{\bf T} {\bf R}} \right)^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} {\bf R}^{\bf T} } \right) = {\bf 0}
$$
i.e. that its columns form a basis  for the space  normal to  $ {\bf r}_{\,1} $ and $ {\bf r}_{\,2} $.

Comment: [+1] Remark: matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}r_1^2&r_2.r_1\\r_1.r_2&r_2^2\end{pmatrix}$$ is a Gram matrix $A^TA$ where $A=[r_1|r_2]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: thanks, and interesting remark: should be interesting to write all down in matrix notation

Comment: ok after looking at it one more time I found $\sqrt{\left\| A-B\right\| _2^2-\left\| ((A-B)\cdot r_2)\ r_1 -((A-B)\cdot r_1)\ r_2\right\| _2^2/\left| M^T M\right| }$ where $M=[r_1|r_2]$.

Comment: @MeMyselfI, clever. Actually upon the hint of *JeanMarie* I was going to rewrite it in matrix notation and added the result to my post.

Comment: @JeanMarie: thanks to your hint, I developed to some extent the matrix notation. May you possibly give some interesting remarks  on the final matrix in $R$ (e.g. idempotency)?

Comment: @G Cab Fine development showing the connection with the vector/matrix presentation of least squares method.

Comment: ok so the matrix formula is basically the distance from $A$ to to projection on the affine hyperplane $B$ plus the space spanned by the columns of $R=(r_1|r_2|...|r_m)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: interesting connection, thanks, so SVD is somewhere behind the curtains.

Comment: @MeMyselfI: don't catch exactly your interpretation. However you raised a very interesting subject, I do not know in depth.

Comment: @G Cab Have a look at the interesting paper (https://www2.pv.infn.it/~fontana/download/lect/Sorenson.pdf).

Comment: @JeanMarie: that's the beauty of maths, the "cross-relation" among different fields !