# Equation of a Hyperplane containing 3 lines

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find the equation of a hyperplane in $R^4$ given the equations of 3 lines that are contained in it?

Comment: Yes, definitely, that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be clear : **in general three (one dimensional) lines aren't situated in a same hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$** ! (think to the analogous case with one dimension less i.e., in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where 2 lines aren't in general in a same plane).

But, it can happen that you know that the three lines do belong to a same hyperplane. In this case, it suffices to have 4 points "in general position = not in a same 2D affine subspace" say $A,B,C,D$ to determine an hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Let $L_1,L_2,L_3$ denote the lines in question.

Therefore, let us take $A \in L_1, B \in L_2, C \in L_3$ and for example $D \in L_1$ again, all assumed distinct ; the equation of this hyperplane will be in coordinates $(X,Y,Z,T)$ (by complete analogy with the 3D case : see equ. (18) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html).

$$\begin{vmatrix}a_x&b_x&c_x&d_x&X\\
a_y&b_y&c_y&d_y&Y\\
a_z&b_z&c_z&d_z&Z\\
a_t&b_t&c_t&d_t&T\\
1&1&1&1&1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

where $A=(a_x,a_y,a_z,a_t)$ are the coordinates of $A$, etc. for the other points.

Remarks : 1) Let us insist on the fact that this solution will work under the condition that $A,B,C,D$ are in general position.

2) A criteria (necessary and sufficient condition) for  $L_1,L_2,L_3$ to belong to a *same* hyperplane is that $d(L_1,L_2)=0$ and $d(L_2,L_3)=0$ where $d$ denotes the shortest distance between two lines with the method explained in (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/429434).

**Edit :** There is a different approach, simple to explain if $L_1,L_2,L_3$ pass all through the origin with resp. directing vectors $V_1,V_2,V_3$. As we are looking for an equation  of the hyperplane of the form

$$uX+vY+wZ+sT=0$$

we know that $(u,v,w,s)$ are the coordinates of a normal vector $N$.

Therefore, it remains to write a linear system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns expressing the 3 orthogonalities : $V_1^TN=0, V_2^TN=0, V_3^TN=0$ and solve it. The solution will depend upon a parameter which is... normal.

This operation is equivalent to obtaining the kernel of the $3 \times 4$ matrix with rows the resp. coordinates of $V_1,V_2,V_3$.

Comment: So if the given lines, passing through the origin, have the equations $r(0,1,0,0)$, $s(0,0,1,0)$, $t(0,0,0,1)$, then I can take $A$, $B$ and $C$ to be the points corresponding to $r = s = t = 1$? And plugging the coordinates in the given determinant would then result in the equation of the Hyperplane? Am I making the right conclusion?

Comment: You hadn't said that your lines were passing through the origin. Yes do as you said $r=s=t=1$, then as you need a fourth point, just take the origin O with coordinates (0,0,0,0) as point D, and expand your determinant for example with respect to its fourth column.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot.

Comment: Please, see the Edit I have added.